# Wordpress login FIRST then SSO to 3rd party platform

Tags: wordpress, redirect, authentication, single-sign-on

I am not a developer but not a total noob either.

I need some advice on how to implement the correct solution to my problem, and your help would be VERY much appreciated.

I have a WP site (www.mysite.com), I have the my users signing up on WP and once signed in they can navigate the site and change and check various things on their front-end user profile page. Now the problem comes in where I am using a 3rd party LMS platform running on a subdomain where I have courses my users can take (learn.mysite.com) - This platform at the default level requires users to sign up, and then via a shortcode placed on the WP user profile page it generates a login form. They then need to login to that platform from the main site and get redirected to the LMS platform. The problem is I DO NOT want my users to sign up again and have to 'login' a 2nd time, they should be able to 'login' by clicking a simple button on their profile page and get redirected (SSO) from WP to the application. i.e The application should realize the user exists in my WP databse and 'let them in'

Now, The 3rd party platform does offer SSO support for SAML 2.0 and LDAP. So how can I make this work with my WP site as I need it explained above?

In short What I need:
Users login to my WP site, with their WP login details, WITHOUT being automatically redirected to 3rd party platform. THEN, when they choose to start learning click a simple link/button (placed on their profile page for example) and get passed seamlessly (SSO) to the platform?

I hope this makes sense, and how can I achieve this?